# Multiple different event listeners in for loop

Tags: javascript

The code below always returns undefined. Why is this? I want the event listener to respond with the string of the index.

Thanks

```
var array = ["Hey", "Hi", "Hello"];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var box = document.createElement("div");
  box.className = "box";
  box.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert(array[i]);
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: Search for "JavaScript creating handlers in a loop"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is asked frequently. JavaScript doesn't have block scope. Variable scope is only created when you invoke a function. So to scope your `i` to the current loop iteration, you need to reference it in a function invocation that also creates the handler.

```
// Create a function that returns a function
function createHandler(i) {
    // The value of `i` is local to this variable scope

    // Return your handler function, which accesses the scoped `i` variable
    return function() {
        alert(array[i]);
    }
}
```

---

```
var array = ["Hey", "Hi", "Hello"];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var box = document.createElement("div");
  box.className = "box";

  // Invoke the `createHandler`, and pass it the value that needs to be scoped.
  // The returned function will use its reference to the scoped `i` value.
  box.addEventListener("click", createHandler(i), false);
}
```

---

I would strongly encourage you to use named functions for this instead of the trendy inline function invocations. It's potentially more efficient, and the function name provides documentation as to the purpose of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the click handler in a closure, to create a local copy of `i`:

```
box.addEventListener("click", (function(i) { 
  return function() {
    alert(array[i]);
  }
})(i), false);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DYdnw/)

The way your code is now, `i` ends up with a value of 3, and `array[3]` is of course undefined.  The above creates 3 copies of `i` with values 0, 1, 2.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the simplest solution would be this:

```
box.addEventListener("click", alert.bind(window, array[i]), false);
```

But this won't work in IE<9.